# How can I `source` a file on my path and have it tab-complete?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that I want to run with `source` and it is on my path so if I start typing the name and hit tab it autocompletes...

```
foo.sh
```

but if I try this...

```
source  foo (then hit the tab button)
```

it does not autocomplete. It is searching my working directory, but not searching my path. Is there anyway to make it find the file that is in my path?

I have bash version `3.2.57(1)-release`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this into your bashrc:

```
complete -c source
```

`-c` stands for *command names* which will effectively search in PATH. But that requires that the files are executable. You could elaborate on that and program a custom completion function which uses `find` to retrieve all shell scripts in PATH.

Comment: "If filename does not contain a
              slash, filenames in PATH are used to find the directory containing  filename."

Comment: See also the `shopt` option `sourcepath`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash built-in commands "complete, compgen, compopt" to do a customized completion for "source".

Link --> https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html